# Parse HTML Content and Fetch Text in JAVA, Android

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

I am working in Android application which fetch html data from website and parse only text (How it works, Search, Community etc) and display on screen.

I managed to fetch the data from website and i can see hundreds of line on mobile screen. 
But now i am bit confused, How to parse this data.

As you can see there are different javascrip and html tags

```
<metaame=
<a href="http://www.blabla.com/how-it-works">
<div id="
<p>
```

and data is wrapped in it. Do we have something in java which can parse all tags and return only text. (in worst case if we do not have anything like this so i can fetch data with in "< p >" tag).
follings are the few lines from my working html content.

```
<metaame="viewport ontent="width=device-width">
    <title>Blabla | Verified phone Community</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Blabla is the world’s largest verified mobile phone community dedicated to helping you take the right call through Caller ID and number search.">
    <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=448142450">
    <meta name="inmobi-site-verification" content="1bed864abfbc5b2b838ca0bfd6a4331">
<div class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-menu-inner">
    <a href="http://www.blabla.com/">Search</a>
    <a href="http://www.blabla.com/how-it-works">How it works</a>
    <a href="/careers">Jobs</a>
    <a href="/blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="http://www.blabla.com/support">Support</a>
    <a class="flat-button-teal" href="http://www.blabla.com/download"><i class="icon-download icon-16"></i> Get the app</a> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div> 
    <div class="large-6 columns section-padding"> 
    <h2>Download now</h2> 
    <p>Find phone numbers, connect with people and make your phonebook beautiful.</p> 
    <p><strong>Email me a download link.</strong></p> 
    <form id="download-email-form" action="/download" method="POST" class="download-form clearfix"> 

    <button class="right" type="submit">&nbsp;</button><div class="input-holder"><input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email"></div> 
    <div class="download-form-recaptcha"> 
    <div id="recaptcha_widget">
<ul class="footer-nav-menu">
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-title">
    This is us </li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/how-it-works">How it works</button></li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/about">About</button></li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/team">Meet the team</button></li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/story">Our story</button></li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/ambassadors">Ambassadors</button></li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/jobs">Jobs</button></li>
    <li class="footer-nav-menu-item"><button class="button-anchor" data-href="http://www.blabla.com/contact">Contact</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking into a Java HTML parser like this: http://jsoup.org/